# Qual a diferença de "ir a" e "ir para"?

Tags: concordância-verbal, preposições, regência

A regência do verbo ***ir*** aceita as preposições ***a*** e ***para***, mas qual é a diferença?

Exemplos:

> Irei à casa de meus pais amanhã.
>
> Irei para casa de meus pais amanhã.

Qual a diferença de “ir a” e “ir para”?

Comment: Pelo que me lebro, "ir a" é mais temporario, tipo "ir a praia". "Ir para" é mais permanente, "em Setembro vou para Inglaterra". É isso?

Comment: No Brasil tanto faz.

Comment: @bfavaretto A sério? Tu dizes *espera um pouco, vou para a cozinha buscar um suco*?  Em Portugal é obrigatório *vou à cozinha* neste caso.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Como já foi dito, em si, o significado é quase o mesmo, apenas teria uma diferença na permanência da ida.

“Ir a” indica que é uma ida passageira, que será por apenas um tempo, não definitiva.

Já “ir para” seria uma ida definitiva, permanente.

> João pensa em ir a Brasília.

Fazer uma visita, passear, resolver algum assunto, etc.

> João pensa em ir para Brasília.

Se mudar para lá, ir e permanecer ali.

---

Porém, apesar dessa diferença, em situações **in**formais (pelo menos no Brasil) muito dificilmente alguém faz essa diferenciação, dizendo sempre “para” (ou o mais comum “ir em”), mas sem ter em momento algum a intenção de especificar se vai *ficar* ali ou não; simplesmente vai.

Comment: Em Portugal há definitivamente uma diferença: "vou para a caixa" (aguadar na fila e depois pagar), "vou à caixa" (perguntar qualquer coisa à empregada). "vou para casa" (e lá ficar), "vou a casa" (buscar qualquer coisa). Não estou a ver os dois a serem trocados. Claro que nalguns casos é mais difícil de distinguir: "vou para a praia o resto da tarde", "vou à praia o resto da tarde" significam mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

Comment: No Brasil ninguém faz diferença mesmo, acredito que nem em situações formais.

Comment: @bfavaretto Geralmente no Brasil se ouve pessoas dizendo que o mais correto é "ir a" e que "ir para" não é muito correto. (não tenho uma fonte aqui agora, mas é isso que sempre ouvi). Em situações formais, é bem mais comum se ouvir "ir a", mas não sei se é feita essa distinção (nunca parei pra perceber isso).

Comment: B. L., o teu link tá quebrado :(. Eu conseguiria arranjar um que sirva, mas talvez queiras tu tratar disso.

Comment: Outra coisa, eu na frase a seguir aos teu exemplos diria "se mudar para lá, ir e permanecer **lá**" e não "... **ali**". Mais uma diferença entre Portugal e Brasil, talvez?

Comment: @Jacinto Removi a fonte, porque não era um exemplo de fonte confiável e a versão anterior no Wayback Machine fica com o layout todo quebrado. Se encontrar uma fonte alternativa, pode adicionar se quiser, na minha ou na sua resposta. Sobre "ali" vs "lá", tem uma pergunta sobre isso (https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/significado-de-ali-versus-l%C3%A1-e-amigos), embora nunca soube dessa diferenciação, e a maior parte da gente daqui do Brasil também não, sempre usando os dois como sinônimos, e pra mim soa mais natural nessa frase dizer "ali" do que "lá".

Comment: @Artefacto   Temos também em pt-PT "voltar a casa"  como em "Já era noite e eu voltava a casa quando fui abordado por dois estranhos..."  Eu voltava a casa, e não era para sair de novo, era para ficar.  Já ouvi algumas vezes em Portugal.

Answer (score 6):

Esta resposta baseia-se na minha experiência de falante de português europeu, em que há uma diferença marcada entre ***ir a*** e ***ir para***. Vários comentários nesta página sugerem que esta diferença é pouco marcada ou inexistente no Brasil.

### Guia rápido

***Ir a* — ir, estar e voltar:**

> - Em dezembro vou ao Brasil, passar duas semanas de férias.
> - Logo à noite vou à festa da Joana.

***Ir para* — estar ou pôr-se a caminho de:**

> - No sábado vou para o Brasil.
> - Vou para a festa. Vens agora, ou vais mais tarde?

### Explicação longa

Tradicionalmente diz-se, tal como na resposta do Bruno, que se usa ***a*** para estadas relativamente curtas no destino, e ***para*** para estadas relativamente longas ou permanentes. Grosso modo isto é verdade; mas é insuficiente, como mostra o exemplo seguinte:

> (a) Ana: — Vou passar um mês ***ao*** Brasil, sabias? Parto já amanhã.
>   Telefona o Pedro a convidar a Ana para ir à praia no dia seguinte.
>   (b) Ana: — Não posso. Vou amanhã ***para o*** Brasil.

A viagem é a mesma, mas num caso usa-se ***a***, noutro usa-se ***para***. A figura abaixo ilustra a diferença. Com ***a*** a Ana contempla a ida, a estada completa, e o regresso (ou continuação da viagem para outro lugar); com ***para***, contempla a ida, mas não a estada completa nem o regresso.

[image]

Por isso *vou amanhã **ao** Brasil* é impossível neste contexto, porque implicaria ir e voltar no mesmo dia. Em (a), *passar um mês* destaca a estada completa, daí usar-se ***a***. Não direi que *vou passar um mês **para o** Brasil* seja impossível, mas soaria muito estranho. O Google search confirma a minha estranheza: 24 *vou passar um mês/dois meses/uns meses* seguido de *ao/à/a* contra apenas 1 seguido de *para o/para a/para*; se for *uma semana*, é setenta contra zero (excluí falsos positivos).

Podemos generalizar a figura do ***ir para***. As razões de não se contemplar a estada completa e regresso podem ser várias: a estada pode ser curta, mas o locutor quer focar apenas a ida; ou a estada pode ser permanente ou de duração indeterminada. A frase (b) presta-se em princípio a várias interpretações: ir passar o resto da vida no Brasil, ir por alguns anos, um mês ou só uns dias. O Pedro, sem perguntar mais nada, só poderia saber qual destas opções é verdadeira se tivesse conhecimento suficiente da vida da Ana.

O exemplo da pergunta é do mesmo tipo.

> Irei ***à*** casa dos meus pais amanhã,

é em Portugal interpretado como ir e voltar amanhã (ou ir e continuar no mesmo dia para outro lugar); enquanto

> irei ***para*** casa dos meus pais amanhã

implica que amanhã a estada ainda não estará completa e que se fica lá pelo menos até depois de amanhã.

No nosso exemplo nós forçamos a escolha entre ***a*** e ***para*** com o *amanhã* e o *passar um mês*. No exemplo seguinte os indicadores do momento de partida e duração da estada estão apenas implícitos, mas forçam igualmente a escolha entre ***a*** e ***para***:

> (c) Bela: — Vou ***para a*** reunião. Vens?
>   João: — Não, quero acabar uma coisa.
>   (d) Bela: — Não vens ***à*** reunião?!
>   (e) João: — Vou ***à*** reunião, mas não vou já. Ainda faltam dez minutos; já lá vou ter.

Em (c) a Bela usa ***para*** para focar a ida; é como se dissesse, *vou agora pôr-me a caminho da reunião*. Em (d) e (e), foca-se a estada completa na reunião, como se se dissesse, *participarei na reunião*. Em (c), *vou à reunião* faria sentido se estivesse em dúvida se a Bela iria ou não à reunião, e ela quisesse então anunciar que sim, que iria (e a reunião não teria que ser naquele momento; poderia ser até noutro dia).

Na verdade, com eventos, como reunião, aula, festa, jantar, manif, cinema, concerto, etc., *ir ao evento* significa intenção de participar no evento ou assistir ao evento (ou o verbo que for mais apropriado); *ir para o evento* significa estar a caminho do evento:

> (f) Hoje não vou ***à*** escola porque estou doente.
>
> (g) David: — Aonde vais com tanta pressa? Laura: — Vou ***para a*** escola; já estou atrasada.

Mesmo estando a caminho de um evento, o locutor pode preferir focar a participação no evento em vez da deslocação até ao local. Suponhamos que a Laura está a caminho de um concerto, e o David pergunta *aonde vais com tanta pressa?* A resposta mais natural é a que dá a informação mais relevante, e isso depende de o David já saber ou não que a Laura ia a um concerto. Se (a Laura penar que) o David não sabe, o mais natural é responder, *vou **a** um concerto*, focando a participação no evento; se ele já sabe, o mais natural é *vou **para** o concerto*, focando o que ela está a fazer no momento.

Nalguns contextos não faz grande diferença usar-se ***a*** ou ***para***. Suponhamos que o Tiago vem procurar a Carla, mas encontra a mãe dela, que lhe explica que a Carla não está. As opções (h), (i) e (j) poderiam ser usadas para o efeito; só a (k) não faria sentido:

> (h) A Carla foi ***para a*** praia.
>   (i) A Carla foi ***à*** praia.
>   (j) A Carla ***já*** foi ***para*** a praia.
>   (k) *A Carla ***já*** foi ***à*** praia.

As opções (h) e (i) dão a mesma informação. Toda a gente sabe que quando se vai à praia, se fica lá umas horas. Portanto foque-se (h) a deslocação para a praia ou (i) a ida, estada e regresso, dá no mesmo: a Carla está ou a caminho da praia ou está na praia, e só volta mais tarde (a opção (i) é compatível com a Carla já ter regressado, mas o contexto permite concluir que não é assim). A opção (j) dá a mesma informação, mas pressupõe que o Tiago já sabia que a Carla ia à praia nesse dia. Já (k) tem um significado diferente: a Carla já fez uma sessão de praia (nessa estação balnear), possivelmente dias ou semanas antes; o ***a*** indica estada completa e regresso, e o *já* com o verbo no pretérito perfeito indica que tudo isso já aconteceu. *Já foi para* indica apenas que ela já saiu de casa em direção à praia.

Muitos verbos funcionam só com ***para***. Uns, como *emigrar*, pressupõem uma estada indefinidamente longa no destino. Outros põem o foco no momento da partida, como *partir* e * abalar*; contraste-se com *ir a/para*:

> (l) O primeiro-ministro partiu ***para*** Madrid para conversações como o seu homólogo espanhol.
>
> (m) O primeiro-ministro foi ***a/para*** Madrid para conversações como o seu homólogo espanhol.

Como em (i), *a* em (m) é compatível com ele já ter regressado de Madrid; *para* não é.

Finalmente, contrariamente a muitas explicações que encontrei, ***ir a*** é compatível com estadas longas:

> A mão de Zola não lhe tremeu ao escrever o J’accuse e por o ter escrito contra o poder no poder foi passar uns anos a Inglaterra. [Blog Portugal dos Pequeninos](http://portugaldospequeninos.blogs.sapo.pt/778754.html)
>
> João Pitta de Ortigueira […] Passou depois a viver na cidade de Tanger onde casou e deixou descendência. Parece que depois de viúvo, já velho foi passar uns anos a Caminha sendo em 1504 juiz ordinário nessa vila [Geneall: Pitta de Castro](http://geneall.net/pt/forum/37270/pita-de-castro-castro-pita/)

Mas eu consigo imaginar *vir a* com uma estada de trinta e tal anos:

> Deus filho fez-se homem e veio à Terra iluminar o caminho dos homens.

Answer (score 4):

No Brasil, coloquialmente, usa-se preferencialmente "para", ou melhor "pra", em quase todas as situações. Em algumas situações prefere-se "a".  Exemplos:

- "Vou à praia amanhã." (talvez para evitar o cacófato "vou pra praia")
- "Vou ao cinema"
- "Eu não vou à aula hoje"

Com frequência, ouve-se também formas incorretas como: "vou na casa de fulana", "você vai na festa?"  uma vez que o correto seria "Vou à casa de fulana. Estou na casa de fulana".

Já com o  verbo voltar, no brPT ouve-se apenas "voltar para casa", enquanto que em Portugal já ouvi a forma "Voltar a casa" algumas vezes.

Comment: No Brasil, o único lugar onde ouço alguém falar "ir a" é na televisão, seja em jornais, programas diversos, ou novelas infantis ou com atores amadores, fora isso apenas ouço "ir para".

Comment: @BrunoLopes  Eu pessoalmente frequentemente uso "vou a/à"  e costumava corrigir meus filhos quando diziam "vou na".  Na cidade onde vivo a maioria das pessoas dizem "ir à praia".

Comment: É, "ir na" também é bem comum, sendo até mais do que "ir para/pra".