# Significado de "ali" versus "lá" e amigos

Tags: advérbios

Fiquei surpreso quando vi [esta definição de "ali"](http://www.aulete.com.br/ali) no Aulete (numeração dos exemplos minha):

> **1.** Em lugar distinto daquele em que se está, que pode ser próximo ou distante; naquele lugar: (1) *Por favor, deixem suas malas ali.*, (2) *Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar ali até o verão.*

Ora, eu nunca me passaria pela cabeça dizer a segunda frase. Eu diria:

> (3) Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar **lá** até o verão.

"Aí" também me parece possível (embora não tão apropriado como "lá"), mas não "acolá" ou "além":

> (4) Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar aí até ao verão.
>   (5) *Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar acolá até ao verão.
>   (6) *Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar além até ao verão.

Sou só eu?

Comment: Eu também diria *vai ficar lá*, mas tenho ideia de já ter visto *ali* usado dessa maneira.

Comment: @Jacinto os São-tomenses dizem muito isso.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30191/discussion-between-jacinto-and-jorge-b).

Comment: A língua Portuguesa é constituída de milhares de palavras e expressões. Muitas delas caíram no desuso ou são usadas muito raramente.  E concordo contigo, Artefacto. Eu diria "vai ficar lá até o verão"  embora não me pareceria errado se eu ouvisse alguém dizer "ali".  Soaria estranho, sem dúvida, mas não errado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (DACL) concorda com o Aulete, e eu concordo com o Artefacto. Nomeadamente este exemplo do DACL tal como o do Aulete não me entram na cabeça:

> (a) Nasceu em Angola mas nunca mais **ali** voltou. (DACL)
>   (b) Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar **ali** até ao verão. (Aulete)

Eu diria

> (a1) Nasceu em Angola mas nunca mais **lá** voltou.
>   (b1) Foi para a Europa, e vai ficar **lá** até ao verão.

Entre outros significados, o DACL apresenta **ali** como indicando o lugar (ou no lugar ou ao lugar) mencionado anteriormente, e sendo neste sentido sinónimo de **lá** e **aí**. Sendo assim, as frases (a) e (a1) seriam equivalentes, tal como as (b) e (b1). Mas eu creio que esta equivalência entre **ali** e **lá** não corresponde ao uso em Portugal. Vejamos os seguintes exemplos:

> (c) A Ana chegou à China e decidiu ficar **lá** uns tempos. Mandou de **lá** vários postais aos amigos. 
>   (d) Um dia foi visitar um pagode e sentou-se na escadaria a admirar a paisagem. Foi **ali** que ela conheceu o Chung Peng. **Dali** avistava-se a cidade lá em baixo. Chegavam até **ali** os ruídos da cidade.

Neste exemplo, eu não substituiria em (c) os **lá** por **ali**. Aceitaria substituir em (d) os **ali** por **lá**. E parece-me que há aqui um padrão:

> (e) A Ana foi a Nova Iorque. Ficou **lá** duas semanas.
>   (f) Um dia foi ao Central Park. Estava-se **lá** bem. (*Estava-se **ali** bem*, com alguma boa vontade.)
>   (g) Sentou-se num banco à sombra. Estava-se **ali** bem. (Ou *estava-se **lá** bem*.)

Parece-me que o que se passa é o seguinte. Nós usamos **lá** e **ali** para indicar um lugar diferente daquele em que estamos e também diferente daquele em que está o nosso interlocutor. **Ali** é usado para lugares relativamente próximos e à vista, e **lá** para lugares relativamente longe, não necessariamente à vista:

> (h) As chaves estão **ali**, não vês? em cima daquela mesa, junto à janela.
>   (i) Vai ao teu quarto, vê na gaveta da mesinha de cabeceira, que as chaves estão **lá**.

Nos exemplos (d) e (g) nós podemos imaginar-nos a seguir a Ana, de modo que quando ela está sentada na escadaria ou no banco, o lugar está à nossa vista, e por isso podemos usar **ali**. Quando ela está na China, exemplo (c), não usamos **ali**: ou nós não estamos na China, e então a China está muito longe e fora da nossa vista; ou se podemos ver a China é porque estamos lá, e então nem **ali** nem **lá** se aplicariam. Diríamos, *veio visitar a China e ficou cá uns tempos.* Passa-se o mesmo com Nova Iorque.

Para indicar um lugar literalmente à vista, que não é onde estamos nem onde o interlocutor está, além de **ali**, podemos também usar **acolá** e **alem**. Eu diria que **acolá** e **além** usam-se preferencialmente para lugares relativamente afastados, enquanto **ali** é usado preferencialmente para lugares próximos.

Conclusão relativamente à nossa discordância com os dicionários. Tal como é usado em Portugal, **ali** indica o lugar mencionado anteriormente, se a narrativa for propícia a que nós nos imaginemos a observar esse lugar de curta distância (ou se nó o podermos ver de facto, claro). Caso contrário, usa-se **lá**. Mesmo quando **ali** é possível, o **lá** também é, mas aí já não nos imaginamos **lá** ao pé.

Comment: As frases de d) soar-me-ia melhor com "aí", mas não sei bem porquê. Se estivermos a apontar um objeto, é clara a diferença ("aí" implica que o objeto está perto do interlocutor, "ali" algo afastado dos dois, mas ainda relativamente perto, "aqui" perto do locutor, "além"/"acolá" longe de ambos, mas para onde ainda conseguimos apontar, e "lá" qualquer coisa fora de vista). Mas nestes contextos mais abstratos, a situação complica-se.

Comment: Também concordo com o *aí* na (d). Curiosamente, na (g) já prefiro o *ali*.

Comment: No Brasil, em relação ao uso corriqueiro do 'lá' e do 'ali', eu percebo que o 'lá' sempre aparece depois do verbo ("Ana foi a Nova York. [Ana] Ficou lá duas semanas") e 'ali' sempre antes do verbo ("Ana foi a Nova York. Ali [Ana] ficou duas semanas"). No meu meio, a primeira forma - usando o 'lá' - é a mais comum. E se me recordo bem, a segunda forma - usando o 'ali' - só vi na literatura mesmo.

Comment: @PEdroArthur no Brasil, não se poderia dizer "lá em casa come-se tarde", "ficou duas semanas lá", "põe ali naquela mesa" e "foi ali ao fundo que eu tropecei"? Em Portugal, sim.

Comment: @ANeves quais seriam os impeditivos formais? Na minha experiência, "Ficou duas semanas lá na agência do centro e depois devolveram ao remetente", "Ficou duas semanas lá na sua mesa", ou "Ficou duas semanas lá" (subentendido o restante) são formações válidas (e bastante utilizadas). E o "põe ali naquela mesa" também é.

Comment: @ANeves Acho que os teus exemplos são todos consensuais. A espinha está se se diz coisas como "Foi a França, e ficou ali uns meses". Os dicionários dizem que sim, e muitos de nós dizem que não, que diríamos "Foi a França, e ficou lá uns meses."

Comment: @PEdroArthur eu percebi duas coisas do teu comentário. 1) Há duas opções, e 2) a segunda é quase só usada em literatura. A primeira dessas coisas não acho que seja verdade (em Portugal) : `eu percebo que o 'lá' sempre aparece depois do verbo e 'ali' sempre antes do verbo`, e por isso tentei dar contra-exemplos para esclarecer.

Comment: @ANeves entendi. A interrogação ficou escondida no meio das aspas. Eu tentei ressaltar o uso no Brasil em relação a casos semelhantes aos apresentados pelo OP. Desculpe se isso ficou implícito. E sim, seus contraexemplos me parecem válidos. Porém, o mais comum seria ouvir "a gente come tarde lá em casa". Nas outras frases, o 'lá' ou o 'ali' deixariam implícito que o objeto apontado está longe ou perto, respectivamente: se houvesse duas mesas, 'lá' seria a mais longínqua.

Comment: @PEdroArthur Isso do *ali* só aparecer na literatura não me surpreende. Mas em Portugal nós podemos pôr o *lá* antes do verbo: *foi para a França, e por lá ficou, lá casou*. Mas *foi a Paris, e lá ficou duas semanas* soa estranho.

Comment: @Jacinto, só pra deixar claro, o que comentei acima está longe de ser uma regra. É apenas o que ouço corriqueiramente em relação a construções linguísticas semelhantes as citadas pelo OP e ao seu caso letra "d".

Answer (score 3):

Creio que existe uma sensação de maior proximidade ao usar a palavra **ali** , especialmente para localizações ou lugares, não só devido à semelhança com [aqui](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aqui):

> 1. Neste lugar.
>
> ...
>
> 5. (**Opõe-se a ali**, para designar um lugar ou um facto, determinados ou não.)

Como também ao lhe perguntarem:

> Onde está o(a) objecto(pessoa) X?

Caso esteja ao seu alcance (visual mas não táctil), responde mais naturalmente:

> Está ali.

Caso contrário, responde:

> Está lá/acolá (no outro lugar).

Alguns exemplos:

> 1. Estamos com vontade de [ficar ali](http://www.ojogo.pt/Futebol/1a_liga/sporting_braga/interior.aspx?content_id=3105357). (artigo em PT mas frase em BR);
> 2. Eu estava de pé quebrado, então tinha que [ficar ali](http://www.tripadvisor.com.br/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g1056623-d3459864-i148111549-Pousada_Cantinho_das_Pedras-Arraial_do_Cabo_State_of_Rio_de_Janeiro.html) o tempo todo. (BR);
> 3. O que dizer olhando para essas fotos? Vontade de [ficar ali](http://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g562810-d2155360-i141744110-Dea_del_Mare_ShardanaSail-Palau_Province_of_Olbia_Tempio_Sardinia.html). (BR);
> 4. Atos 15:34: Mas pareceu bem a Silas [ficar ali](http://bibliaportugues.com/acts/15-34.htm). (BR);
> 5. Exatamente [ali](http://www.editorajc.com.br/2013/12/gesto-data-estadio-local-cerimonia-historia-nao-esquecera-dia-nao-coincidencia/) ... (BR);
> 6. [Ali](http://www.familiaabordo.com/2014/11/praca-do-comercio-bela-entrada-de-lisboa.html) foi o local do palácio dos reis de Portugal durante cerca de dois séculos (BR para audiência PT?).

Por isso a frase:

> Foi para a Europa, e vai [ficar ali](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1341/156) até o verão.

Pode indicar uma proximidade maior, talvez por o interlocutor apontar/referir uma fotografia ou mapa ao seu alcance, quando pronunciou essa mesma frase. Logo a expressão "ficar lá" poderia ser um pouco desadequada neste contexto.

Compare também com a [resposta do Jacinto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1342/156), exemplos (h) e (i).

Comment: Eu concordo com o *ali* no mapa ou na foto. Mas repara que os dicionários não restringem o uso de *ali* a situações em que haja alguma coisa que se possa apontar.

Comment: @Jacinto exato. Não é necessário uma ligação visual direta, ou seja, parece depender mais do contexto e da situação decorrente.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a minha experiência em Portugal:

*Aqui*, *aí* e *ali* referem-se à posição explícita de algo em relação ao ambiente próximo de quem comunica. Implicando proximidade, especificam se é respectivamente ao comunicador, ao ouvinte, ou a nenhum deles.

Enquanto que *cá* e *lá* exprimem a proximidade de algo com quem comunica, num âmbito de distância. Se é "aqui perto" (cá) ou "lá longe" (lá).

Sendo conceitos parecidos, por vezes podem ser usadas indistintamente.
No entanto, segundo a minha experiência e por implicar proximidade, *ali* nunca seria usado para algo distante como `foi para a Europa, e vai ficar ali até o verão`.

---

As palavras *aqui*, *aí* e *ali* são usadas para indicar um lugar perto, que frequentemente está visível. E explicitam se está:

- Aqui, na vizinhança de mim;
- Aí, na vizinhança de com quem se fala;
- Ou ali, fora da vizinhança de ambos.

> Tens frio? Sai d**aí** de perto da janela e vem para **aqui** para perto da lareira. Se quiseres, tira uma mantinha d**ali** do armário.

---

As palavras *cá* e *lá* são usadas para indicar qual a relação de distância entre algo e quem fala: se algo é/está/se-passou "aqui na zona em que eu estou" ou "numa zona longe de mim".

> Voltei, voltei, voltei de **lá**; ainda agora estava em França e agora já estou **cá**. ♪