# «Ir no» versus «ir a» versus «ir para» no português brasileiro

Tags: significado, diferenças, português-brasileiro, preposições

A diferença entre ***ir a*** e ***ir para*** já foi discutida na pergunta [Qual a diferença entre ***ir a*** e ***ir para***](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/791/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-ir-a-e-ir-para). Mas eu ouço brasileiros usar também ***ir em*** em situações parecidas. Por exemplo (ênfase minha):

> Hoje outra vez eu ***vou no*** baile à procura de alguém [[Canção *O Baile* de *Tribo da Periferia*]](http://www.vagalume.com.br/tribo-da-periferia/no-baile.html)
>
> Olha, ***vamos na*** dança do Caxambu [[Canção *Caxambu* de Almir Guineto]](http://www.vagalume.com.br/almir-guineto/caxambu.html)
>
> E aí menina, quem é o teu homem?
> ***Vamos no*** cartório pra te passar pro meu nome [[Canção *Quem É o Teu Homem?* de Mc Maromba]](https://www.letras.mus.br/mc-maromba/quem-e-o-teu-homem/)

Esta questão já chegou ao [Ciberdúvidas (*vou no cinema*)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/vou-no-cinema/15633), mas a resposta deles, baseada nos étimos latinos, parece-me altamente insatisfatória.

Então qual é a diferença de ***ir em*** relativamente a ***ir a*** e ***ir para*** no português brasileiro?

Comment: Já ouvi ambas as formas: "Vou no banheiro." e "Vou ao banheiro." Durante o tempo que vivi no Brasil, usava a preposição **_em_** como complemento de **_ir_**, de maneira coloquial. Sempre tive a impressão de ser um erro.

Comment: Pode servir também para expressar uma forma de ir a algum sítio. Por exemplo: "Vou no ônibus." como "Vou de autocarro."

Comment: @felipe.zkn Em Portugal também se diz «vou no autocarro das 8h15», por exemplo. Eu aqui estou interessado só em coisas como «vou no banheiro» vs. «vou ao banheiro» vs. «vou para o banheiro».

Comment: Será que o uso do 'em' não pode ser explicado pelo primeiro aprendizado do sentido de lugar, empregando-se 'em' para indicar o lugar em que está: "em casa", "na escola", e tornando-se hábito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ir em" como sinônimo de "ir a" é uma construção coloquial, rejeitada pelo padrão.

É aceitável no padrão em construções tais como "fui no vôo das sete e meia", ou "vou no carro do João", como apontado pelo felipe.zkn (mas aí não é exatamente sinônimo de "ir de").

Usa-se também em construções como "vamos em comissão", "fomos em comitiva", "íamos em doze, mas o Zé faltou, então fomos em onze", etc.

---

Por outro lado, há também uma diferença sutil entre "ir a" e "ir em", mesmo na acepção em que são quase sinônimos. Talvez seja melhor partir de exemplos concretos para ilustrar o que quero dizer:

> Vou à casa do João.

e

> Vou na casa do João.

significam basicamente a mesma coisa.

Mas,

> Vou em casa e já volto.

implica que vou à minha casa, mas não se diz

> *Vou a casa e já volto.

e na verdade preferiríamos

> Vou para casa e já volto.

E,

> Vamos ao palácio do governo entregar nossa lista de reivindicações.

não pode ser substituída por

> *Vamos no palácio do governo entregar nossa lista de reivindicações.

Talvez ir ao palácio do governo demande uma formalidade maior, ou talvez o uso de "em" implique em efetivamente entrar no lugar aonde/"nonde" se vai. A segunda hipótese me parece mais provável, por que não vejo reparo em

> Vou no palácio do governo tomar um cafezinho com meu amigo, o presidente.

Ou talvez seja meramente uma questão idiossincrática; o comportamento das preposições é muito arbitrário e convencional. Para ficar no caso de "ir" + prep., vejamos:

> Vou de avião.
>
> Vou de táxi.
>
> Vou de carroça.
>
> Vou de submarino.
>
> Vou de pó de pirlimpimpim.

Mas,

> *Vou de cavalo.
>
> Vou **a** cavalo.

Comment: Tirando o *ir em* = *ir a*, o uso é igual ao de Portugal. Tirando também, talvez, o *íamos em doze*; aqui mais depressa se diria *íamos doze*.

Comment: Interessante, *ir a cavalo* parece ser uma exceção, porque eu diria *vou de burro/camelo/elefante*. Tu dirias "vou para casa buscar a carteira, volto já" ou "vou para casa tirar o frango do congelador/ver se chegou correio, volto já"? Aqui diríamos *vou a casa*.

Comment: @Jacinto Aqui não se diz "ir a casa"; no máximo se escreve. Ou eu vou "para casa" ou "em casa" - ou, mais raramente, "à minha casa". "Ir em casa" é sempre algo transitório - vou lá e volto logo. "Para casa", sem nada mais, é sempre no sentido de ir para casa e ficar lá até o dia seguinte ou pelo menos até à noite: *Chega de trabalhar, vou para casa.* *A festa está sem graça, vou pra casa.* Mas sim, diríamos *vou pra casa buscar a carteira/trocar de roupa/tomar um banho, volto em seguida*.

Comment: @Jacinto Também diríamos "vou de burro". Mas "a cavalo" parece significar algo mais amplo do que simplesmente um animal da espécie, por que dizemos, *Lá vem ele, a cavalo no burro".

Comment: Notem que _ir em_ não é necessariamente um barbarismo quanto um resquício do latim _ire in_ + acusativo, que desapareceu em Portugal.

Comment: Luís, voltei a isto a propósito de uma [recomendação](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/estar-vs-ser-localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) de não usar *ir em (lugares)*. Portanto, *ir à casa do João*, tudo bem, mas não _*ir a casa_. O problema é a preposição *a* sem artigo? Como é que é com *vou a/em Porto Alegre/Curitiba (entregar uma encomenda, ou outra coisa rápida)?*

Answer (score 1):

Em quanto **ir a** e **ir para** são formalmente aceitos, **ir no** é utilizado de forma mais coloquial.
Conforme já respondido pela própria questão citada na pergunta:

- **ir a** - Se dirigir para um local e ficar temporariamente;
- **ir para** - Se dirigir para um local e ficar permanentemente;

Por outro lado, todas as formas de **ir em**, **ir no**, e **ir na** tem-se a idéia de forma temporária, com o mesmo significado de **ir a**, por exemplo:

> Eu vou a Brasília
>
> Eu vou em Brasília

Ou ainda se usarmos um local:

> Eu vou ao Cartório
>
> Eu vou no Cartório

Essas duas formas darão uma ideia de permanência temporária.

Comment: Obrigado. Estava a ver que ninguém respondia a esta pergunta! Agora ainda vais ganhar uma "revival badge" e uma "necromancer badge" com esta resposta. Eu tinha uma certa suspeita que *ir em* era um equivalente coloquial a *ir a*, mas não tinha a certeza. Já agora, dizer que *ir para* implica ida permanente é apenas uma aproximação: *vou agora para casa* não significa que vou ficar em casa até morrer. Vê a minha resposta à outra pergunta.

Comment: Depois que escrevi, pensei também sobre o ir para. Concordo contigo, eu falo por exemplo: "vou para o trabalho", ou "a semana que vem vou para Brasília". E em nenhum desses casos quer dizer algo permanente. Por outro lado, acho que esses exemplos são coloquiais. De repente um professor de português possa nos ajudar. ;)

Comment: Creio que esses exemplos são corretíssimos quer na linguagem coloquias, quer na formal. Se me disseres que vais **para** o trabalho, eu entendo que vais trabalhar, e regressas no fim do dia; se me disseres que vais **ao** trabalho, eu imagino que vais e voltas logo de seguida (para ir entregar ou buscar qualquer coisa, por exemplo).