# Estar vs Ser + localização

Tags: português-brasileiro

Eu sei quando usamos *estar* e *ser*, mas eu vi um exemplo com *estar* que me confundiu um pouco.

> Eu *fui* para Rio com amigos. Nós *estivemos* no Pão de açúcar.

Por que não é como:

> Eu *fui* para Rio com amigos. Nós *fomos* no Pão de açúcar.

ou

> Eu *estive* para Rio com amigos. Nós *estivemos* no Pão de açúcar.

Comment: Você não usou o verbo *ser*, usara apenas os verbos *ir* e *estar*. Não há problemas em usar o verbo *ir* numa oração e o verbo *estar* noutra. **OBS.:** Evite usar o verbo **ir** (*fomos*, por exemplo) com a preposição *em*. Isso passa uma ideia de meio de transporte. O ideal é: *Nós fomos **a**o Pão de Açúcar* e *Nós fomos **n**o meu carro*

Comment: @ValdeirPsr pode formular uma resposta? E já agora se poder incluir que "fui" pode ser do verbo ser e ir.

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda exatamente, mas... `Nós fomos = We went`; `Nós estivemos = We've been`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não usou o verbo **ser**, usara apenas os verbos **ir** e **estar** no *pretérito perfeito*.

Quanto a construção das orações, há problema nenhum em usar diferentes verbos em orações distintas.

Acredito que a confusão com os verbos **ir** e **ser**, deva-se a ambos possuírem as mesmas palavras, mas com significados diferentes. No Português, chamamos isso de palavras homônimas.

Isso acontece com os verbos **ser** e **ir** nos tempos *Pretérito Perfeito* e *Pretérito Mais-que-perfeito* do modo indicativo; e *Pretérito Imperfeito* e *Futuro* do modo subjuntivo. Porém, cuidado com o significado.

**Verbo SER**

> Indica estado permanente ou circunstancial; ou mudança ou continuidade de estado.

**Verbo IR**

> Indica locomoção, passa a ideia de meio de transporte

**Conjugações**

**Pretérito Perfeito do Indicativo**

```
|---------------------|-----------|------------|
| Pronome             | Verbo SER | Verbo IR   |
|---------------------|-----------|------------|
| Eu                  | fui       | fui        |
| Tu                  | foste     | foste      |
| Ele                 | foi       | foi        |
| Nós                 | fomos     | fomos      |
| Vós                 | fostes    | fostes     |
| Eles                | foram     | foram      |
```

**Pretérito Mais que Perfeito do Indicativo**

```
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|    Pronome          | Verbo SER | Verbo IR      |
|---------------------|-----------|---------------|
|    Eu               | fora      | fora          |
|    Tu               | foras     | foras         |
|    Ele              | fora      | fora          |
|    Nós              | fôramos   | fôramos       |
|    Vós              | fôreis    | fôreis        |
|    Eles             | foram     | foram         |
```

**Pretérito Imperfeito do Subjuntivo**

```
|------------------|-----------|----------|
| -- | Pronome     | Verbo SER | Verbo IR |
|------------------|-----------|----------|
| Se | Eu          | fosse     | fosse    |
| Se | Tu          | fosses    | fosses   |
| Se | Ele         | fosse     | fosse    |
| Se | Nós         | fôssemos  | fôssemos |
| Se | Vós         | fôsseis   | fôsseis  |
| Se | Eles        | fossem    | fossem   |
```

**Futuro do Subjuntivo**

```
|------------------|-----------|----------|
| ------ | Pronome | Verbo SER | Verbo IR |
|------------------|-----------|----------|
| Quando | Eu      | for       | for      |
| Quando | Tu      | fores     | fores    |
| Quando | Ele     | for       | for      |
| Quando | Nós     | formos    | formos   |
| Quando | Vós     | fordes    | fordes   |
| Quando | Eles    | forem     | forem    |
```

> Observação: Evite usar o verbo **ir** (fomos, por exemplo) com a preposição *em*. Isso passa uma ideia de meio de transporte. O ideal é: Nós **fomos** *a*o Pão de Açúcar e Nós **fomos** *n*o meu carro.

**[Fonte](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6250.md)**