# "Vai a Portugal" ou "Vai para Portugal"

Tags: diferenças, diferenças-transatlânticas, significado-em-contexto

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre "Vai a Portugal" é "Vai para Portugal" para os nativos portugueses, tanto brasileiro como europeu.

Existe alguma diferença entre so ir de férias ou morar permanentemente nestas duas frases?

Comment: Roberto, a tua pergunta é o que nós chamamos uma duplicata: já está respondida em [Qual a diferença de "ir a" e "ir para"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/791/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-de-ir-a-e-ir-para).